# 'No such file or directory' when running Makefile script

Tags: makefile, cassandra, cql, cqlsh, iterm2

The folder structure is set up like so:

```
Main directory
  \_ keyspaces
    \_ f1
      \_ bootstrap.cql
      \_ anotherFolder
        \_ 0001-something.cql
    \_ f2
      \_ bootstrap.cql
      \_ anotherFolder
        \_ 0001-something.cql
        \_ 0002-moreSomething.cql
```

I have a Makefile in the main directory which contains this code:

```
do_stuff:
    for ks in keyspaces/*; do \
        cqlsh -f "$${ks}/bootstrap.cql"; \
    done
```

When I run `make do_stuff` from my terminal (using iTerm2) inside of the main directory, I get an error, stating the following:

```
Can't open 'keyspaces/f1/bootstrap.cql': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'keyspaces/f1/bootstrap.cql'
command terminated with exit code 1
Can't open 'keyspaces/f2/bootstrap.cql': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'keyspaces/f2/bootstrap.cql'
command terminated with exit code 1
make: *** [do_stuff] Error 1
```

However, if I run this in my terminal: `cat keyspaces/f1/bootstrap.sql` I get the contents of that file printed out, so the path is correct and it does exists, but cqlsh can't recognize it?

Looking at [the Cassandra/cqlsh docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html), it looks like I'm using the `-f` command properly, so I don't know why I'm getting the errors.

Comment: How about `cat keyspaces/f1/bootstrap.cql`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with simple steps to eliminate potential issues

```
.
├── Makefile
└── keyspaces
    ├── f1
    │   └── bootstrap.cql
    └── f2
        └── bootstrap.cql
```

with following Makefile, works fine

```
do_stuff:
    for ks in keyspaces/*; do \
        cat "$${ks}/bootstrap.cql"; \
    done
```

execution

```
make
for ks in keyspaces/*; do \
      cat "${ks}/bootstrap.cql"; \
    done
a
b
```

Double check, that inside `Main directory` you can call

```
cqlsh -f "keyspaces/f1/bootstrap.cql"
```

Maybe you can delegate this to `find`?

```
do_stuff:
    find `pwd` -name "*.cql" -exec cat {} \;
```

Comment: The first loop with the `cat` works fine, however, your last line of code you suggested running inside the `Main directory` throws that not-found error, so there must be something wrong with that Cassandra command I'm trying to run :/ I'll post up update if I figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Just one more question, maybe instead of makefile you can simply use find? find `pwd` -name "*.cql" -exec cqlsh -f {} \;

Comment: It seems to work, but when I use it in the loop I get `find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"`

Comment: Your solution works as well actually (I wasn't able to edit previous comment after 5 mins). However, I'll probably open a new more specific question to figure out why I still can't run `.cql` files with the `-f` option using cqlsh, i.e. `cqlsh -f 'somefile.cql'`